# Conda environment is supposed to be python3.5, but using python 2.7

Tags: python, conda, environment

I created a conda environment with a specific version of python (3.5) like so:

```
conda create --name py35 python=3.5
```

Then I activate it and then type 'python' and I get Python 2.7.16.
Is that supposed to happen?  I thought I would get Python 3.5.  I try typing 'python3' or 'python3.5', but neither works.
How would I open the python interpreter?

```
(py35) C:\Users\bosr>python
Python 2.7.16 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 14 2019, 15:42:17) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

```
(py35) C:\Users\bosr>python3
'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

```
(py35) C:\Users\bosr>python35
'python35' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

```
(py35) C:\Users\bosr>python3.5
'python3.5' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

```
(py35) C:\Users\bosr>python3
'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Please show me the light.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you have Python 2.7 installed system-wide and on your PATH? What happens if you run `where python`?

Comment: @GPhilo `where` or `which`?

Comment: Which python shows /c/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python

Comment: I actually installed anaconda3, so I was surprised python2.7 was even available on my system.  I am just learning about environments, but I thought being inside an environment would override the system python and use the environment python.

Comment: @KonradRudolph IIRC, `where` on Windows (don't have access to a windows pc right now, so I can't check).

Comment: 'where python' and 'which python' both work by the way... and return the similar output.

Comment: @RogerJBosCFA just triple-checking: does `python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"` also give the same path to "/c/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python"?

Comment: YES: (py35) C:\Users\bosr>python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe

Comment: Then something is very wrong in the environment. For one thing, the python interpreter as seen from inside the environment should be under C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py35\python.exe, not the "root" one... if you `echo %PATH%` in the py35 env, do you have python listed twice (once base and once in the environment)?

Comment: I don't see python.exe at all.  Here is the start of the output (too big to post in entirety) (py35) C:\Users\bosr>echo %PATH%
C:\Users\bosr\.conda\envs\py35;C:\Users\bosr\.conda\envs\py35\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\bosr\.conda\envs\py35\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\bosr\.conda\envs\py35\Library\bin;C:\Users\bosr\.conda\envs\py35\Scripts;C:\Users\bosr\.conda\envs\py35\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\condabin;C:\Rtools\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin;C:\Rtools\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common

Comment: is there a chance that '''conda remove --name py35 --all'' does not remove everything?  I have created this environment more than once.

Comment: @RogerJBosCFA rather than posting in the comments when people request additional information, please post it to your original question. You can still use the comments to @ tag users if you want to let them know you've updated the question with the requested info.